# Performing addition when creating a string

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I'm creating a number of objects with details read in from an array.  They will have a standard format for one of their instance variables which I'd like to be, in part, an ascending number.  Specifically, I'm creating a load of `Location` objects which I'd like to have a description of "Flat 1", "Flat 2", etc.

I'm wondering though if there is an easy way to perform addition when assigning a value to a `String`.  Stripped down to the relevant part, my code is:

```
int size = locations.size();
Location l;
for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    l = new Location ("Flat " + i + 1); //LINE A
    addLocation(l);
}
//several bits of code have been removed and swapped around here, I realise 
//that that snippet doesn't really perform anything useful
```

However, Java interprets both the "+" symbols in LINE A as concatenation meaning I get "Flat 01", "Flat 11", "Flat 21", etc.

Obviously I could change around the way the loop works, but I was curious as to whether performing calculations in a `myString = value + 2` type statement was possible?

Comment: Have you tried using parentheses around `i + 1`? Note that the expression will be evaluated from left to right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String concatenation is left-associative, so all you have to do is wrap the value you want in parentheses to ensure that it's calculated first:

```
l = new Location ("Flat " + i + 1);
```

is effectively:

```
l = new Location (("Flat " + i) + 1);
```

So `i` is appended to the string `"Flat "` first; and then `1` is appended to that.

Should be:

```
l = new Location ("Flat " + (i + 1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use parentheses:

```
l = new Location ("Flat " + (i + 1)); //LINE A
```